# Magento Form - Multiple Image uploader

Tags: magento-1.7, forms

```
 $fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('featuredsalons')->__('Image'),
          'required'  => true,

        //'multiple'  => true, 
        //'multiple'  => 'multiple', 
          'name'      => 'image',
          'after_element_html' => '<p class="note"><span>Image Dimension: </span></p>'
      ));
```

I have tried above mentiion to allow multple images , but failed.

Comment: If it is enough, you can just add multiple file input fields. Is multiple limited? Or is multiple 0+?

Answer (score 1):

The only "multiple image" widget available in a default Magento install is the EAV Attribute type `gallery`.

I'm pretty sure however that you'll need to implement the same `Adminhtml_Widgets` in order to use it on something other than a product (like a custom EAV Entity with a custom form).

If you just need a custom form (without a custom entity or for a custom Flat entity) you may be better off creating your own `Controllers` and implementing `SWF Upload` yourself using your own logic/structures.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this function `getElementHtml` in this file `lib\Varien\Data\Form\Element\Abstract.php`  like this:

```
public function getElementHtml(){
            if($this->getType()=='file' && $this->getMultiple())
                $_multiple = ' multiple';
            $html = '<input id="'.$this->getHtmlId().'" name="'.$this->getName()
                 .'" value="'.$this->getEscapedValue().'" '.$this->serialize($this->getHtmlAttributes()).$_multiple.'/>'."\n";
            $html.= $this->getAfterElementHtml();
            return $html;
    }
```

after that you able to upload multiple file with your file field

Example:
In form file

```
 $fieldset->addField('optionimage', 'file', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('option_module')->__('Option Image'),
                            'required'  => false,
                            'name'      => 'optionimage[]',
                            'multiple'=>true,
                            'multiple'=>'multiple'
            ));
```

and in your controller

Comment: Never edit core files!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your 'name' value and add '[]', finally it should looks like this:

```
$fieldset->addField('image', 'image', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('featuredsalons')->__('Image'),
      'required'  => true,
      'multiple'  => 'multiple', 
      'name'      => 'image[]',
      'after_element_html' => '<p class="note"><span>Image Dimension: </span></p>'
  ));
```